# Programming Simple Chatterbot in console?

Tags: java, chatbot

Hello I am an amateur coder, so please beware with me.

I don't want to get into the swing/switch dialog programming, therefore I want to make it simple as possible. But again, I don't want my coding to be a lot of if an else statements. I'm looking for more ways to make the chatbot more smooth. I've tried to search and understand strings and arrays but I'm still unaware of how to implement that into my coding.

This is my first attempt to make a simple chatbot

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatBot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello I'm your therapist for today! What's your name? \n");
        String n = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Okay " + n + ", How are you?");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            String inputs = sc.nextLine();
            inputs = inputs.toUpperCase();

            if (inputs.indexOf("FINE") >= 0) {
                System.out.println("That's good to know " + n);
            }

            else if (inputs.indexOf("HI") >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Hello " + n);
            }

            else if (inputs.indexOf("HELP") >= 0) {
                System.out.println("If you seek help, listen to your heart! <3");
            }

            else if (inputs.indexOf("HELP ME") >= 1) {
                System.out.println("I will try my best helping you, what's your problem?");
            }

            // what if bot doesn't know the answer to fyour question/response?
            // The chatbot gives a random respond to unknown questions by the user
            // here the number of random responses are given 4, but in java we start at 0
            // I have made the number to 4, so that the responses can be from between 0 to 3
            // Also I have added Math.random utility and declared it to a double value
            // The "r" is now my random, and I make a new integar to calculate random
            // response
            // by calculating the r times num variables and thereby getting a random value.
            // that random value is declared to "rResponse" and therefore I have assigned
            // the
            // String response to answer/reply depending on the random number that's
            // generated
            // between 0-3
            else {
                final int num = 4;
                double r = Math.random();
                int rResponse = (int) (r * num);
                String response = "";

                if (rResponse == 0) {
                    response = "Hmmm...";
                }

                else if (rResponse == 1) {
                    response = "Okay?...";
                }

                else if (rResponse == 2) {
                    response = "I don't get it...";
                }

                else if (rResponse == 3) {
                    response = "I dont quite follow, I'm sorry. Try another question";
                }
                System.out.println(response);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Anyhow, my problem in

```
                else if (inputs.indexOf("HELP ME") >= 1) {
                    System.out.println("I will try my best helping you, what's your problem?"); }
else if (inputs.indexOf("HELP") >= 0) {
                System.out.println("If you seek help, listen to your heart! <3"); }
```

this code is the fact that I can't make it respond to two different userinputs that I want the bot to answer sepereately. For example I want it to respond differently when you say "help me" instead of "help".

Is there any recommendations or ways, that I can do this differently?

Also if anyone can let me know how I can redo all this with another method, by using arraylist? or two dimensional arrays? If it's not too hardcore for a beginner like me. What would the simple way to do this, without having to do all of these if and else statements?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The indexOf method returns zero if the characters match the first characters of the String.  You could store the questions and answers in a tree-like structure, where a question can have multiple answers that each point to another question.  The following article, [A deep dive into trees with Java](https://www.educative.io/blog/data-structures-trees-java) isn't simple to understand, but it's powerful.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thank you for your response, I see there's many ways of building a tree. Digging deep into the article you've posted it seems a little blurry, which data structure would be the best for me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you understand classes, methods, and fields.  If you don't, this explanation won't make any sense.

We're going to build a tree data structure using classes and the `java.util.List` interface.

The first step is to construct a getter / setter class that saves responses and the `List` index to the next question.

Here's that class.

```
public class Response {
    
    private final String response;
    
    private final int responseQuestion;

    public Response(String response, int responseQuestion) {
        this.response = response.toLowerCase();
        this.responseQuestion = responseQuestion;
    }
    
    public boolean doesResponseMatch(String responseString) {
        return responseString.toLowerCase().contains(getResponse());
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public int getResponseQuestion() {
        return responseQuestion;
    }

}
```

The `doesResponseMatch` method determines if the `responseString` typed by the user contains the response `String`.

We save the response as a lower case `String` and convert the user `responseString` to lower case so the contains test is case-independent.

The rest of the class is a typical getter / setter class.

The next step is to create a class that holds a question, a `List` of possible responses, and a default response.  The default response is used in case none of the possible responses matches.

```
public class Question {
    
    private final String question;
    
    private final Response defaultResponse;
    
    private List<Response> possibleResponses;

    public Question(String question, Response defaultResponse) {
        this.question = question;
        this.defaultResponse = defaultResponse;
        this.possibleResponses = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void addPossibleResponse(Response response) {
        this.possibleResponses.add(response);
    }
    
    public Response getPossibleResponse(String responseString) {
        for (Response response : this.possibleResponses) {
            if (response.doesResponseMatch(responseString)) {
                return response;
            }
        }
        
        return this.defaultResponse;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    
}
```

The getPossibleResponse method returns either a matching response or if there are no matches, the default response.

The question can contain zero, one, or many matching responses.  Each response can point to a different question index.

We use a `java.util.ArrayList` to hold the `List`.  Since we're going to add all the questions at one time, an array list is an appropriate structure to hold our tree.

The next step is to create a class to hold our tree structure, which will be a `List` of `Question` instances.

```
public class ResponseTree {
    
    private List<Question> questions;
    
    public ResponseTree() {
        this.questions = new ArrayList<>();
        addQuestionFactory();
    }
    
    private void addQuestionFactory() {
        Response defaultResponse = new Response("", 0);
        String question = "I don't understand your response.";
        addQuestion(question, defaultResponse);
        
        // Add your additional questions / responses here.
        // Using a List means we can point to any question by it's 
        // location number from 0 to List size() - 1.
        // This is a tree structure, stored in a List.
    }
    
    private void addQuestion(String question, Response defaultResponse) {
        this.questions.add(new Question(question, defaultResponse));
    }
}
```

The `addQuestionFactory` is a separate method because it will grow to include all the chatbot questions you want to respond to.  I've included the obvious first question.

You can test this code by writing the rest of the chatbot.  Any response will be answered by the first question.  After you've written the rest of the chatbot, you can add questions and responses to the factory method.

By using classes, we've created a tree structure that looks like this:

```
Tree (List)
    Question
        String
        List of possible responses
        Default response

Response
    String
    Index pointer
```

By using classes, we can hide some of the complexity and make our code easier to understand.

Comment: This is very interesting take on how to do it! Thank you very much, I am already trying to study this tree/like structure. But you're right, it does seem a little to hard to understand in my level of programming, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should turn to `equals`:

```
else if ("HELP ME".equals(inputs)) {
                System.out.println("I will try my best helping you, what's your problem?"); 
} else if ("HELP".equals(inputs)) {
     System.out.println("If you seek help, listen to your heart! <3"); 
}
```

The general practies about comparing to constant String is to put String constant first and the variable second in order to defend NPE( NullPointerException ), in case `inputs` being null.

Go back to your question, I think you can do it better with `HashMap` to avoid `if-else` statements:

```
HashMap<> handlers = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
handlers.add("FINE", () -> {
    System.out.println("That's good to know " + n);
});

.... add other handlers.

do while {
   
    Get your handler from  handlers and call run on it.
    If no handler not found, try randome response.
}
```

It's more efficient than `indexOf` and `equals` operations.

By the way, [Spring Shell](https://projects.spring.io/spring-shell/) is a good starter for writing shell applications.

Comment: Oh I see... I do want it to be more efficient than it is now, it still seems a bit noob-like, I had like to make it a little more advanced than how it is now. Is HashMap the next level, or is there other ways to make it more efficient without having to make it too advanced for myself?

Comment: @Snooppoop HashMap is definitely the next level, It's essential to know the basic data structures like `List` and `Map` etc. that JDK offers in order to write a high performance application

Comment: Again thank you for the quick response, do you think it would be easier to learn just about arrays than to learn about HashMap?

Comment: @Snooppoop I suggest you to follow some Java tutorials, It will teach you from easy to advanced topics.

Comment: Oh I am sure there's plenty of tutorials out there to make understand java better, but that's also the reason I am here. I have been looking at all the tutorials you can find about making a chatbot specially in the area of only using the console not the dialog.
Thank you for your suggestion though.